# java.security.AccessControlException when using Ant, but runs ok when invoking java from console

Tags: java, ant

I have the following **Ant < java >** task:

```
<property name="classpath-run.msg" refid="run.classpath"/>
<echo message="running the app with classpath = ${classpath-run.msg}"/>
<echo message="Java version used (ant.java.version): ${ant.java.version}"/>
<echo message="Java version used (    java.version): ${java.version}"/>
<java classname ="${project.MainClass.name}">
    <permissions>
        <grant class="java.security.AllPermission"/>
        <grant class="javax.management.MBeanTrustPermission" action="register"/>  
    </permissions>
    <classpath refid="run.classpath"/>
</java>
```

When I run **Ant** the execution of the  task fails (see trace below). When I copy-paste the echoed classpath and run my code from the command line with **java -classpath ..** the execution succeeds!

In both cases the same version of **java** is used.

How is it possible that I observe different behavior ? A **java.security.AccessControlException** sits at the root of the stacktrace but I've already granted my **Ant java** task all security permissions, including, explicitly the **MBeanTrustPermission** for the action **register** which also appears in the stack trace.

Trace (when run under **Ant**) is found below:

```
 [java] java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecuteJava.execute(ExecuteJava.java:194)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.run(Java.java:771)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.executeJava(Java.java:221)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.executeJava(Java.java:135)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.execute(Java.java:108)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
 [java]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
 [java]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 [java]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
 [java]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
 [java]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 [java]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.MacroInstance.execute(MacroInstance.java:398)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
 [java]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
 [java]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 [java]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:809)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:217)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)
 [java] Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
 [java]     at TranslationClient.main(TranslationClient.java:5)
 [java]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 [java]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
 [java]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 [java]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecuteJava.run(ExecuteJava.java:217)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecuteJava.execute(ExecuteJava.java:152)
 [java]     ... 34 more
 [java] Caused by: net.sf.ehcache.CacheException: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("javax.management.MBeanTrustPermission" "register")
 [java]     at net.sf.ehcache.management.sampled.SampledMBeanRegistrationProvider.initialize(SampledMBeanRegistrationProvider.java:98)
 [java]     at net.sf.ehcache.management.provider.MBeanRegistrationProviderImpl.initialize(MBeanRegistrationProviderImpl.java:63)
 [java]     at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.doInit(CacheManager.java:454)
 [java]     at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.init(CacheManager.java:374)
 [java]     at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.<init>(CacheManager.java:356)
 [java]     at TranslationCache.<clinit>(TranslationCache.java:10)
 [java]     ... 41 more
 [java] Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("javax.management.MBeanTrustPermission" "register")
 [java]     at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:366)
 [java]     at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:585)
 [java]     at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.checkMBeanTrustPermission(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:1848)
 [java]     at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:322)
 [java]     at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.registerMBean(JmxMBeanServer.java:512)
 [java]     at net.sf.ehcache.management.sampled.SampledMBeanRegistrationProvider.registerCacheManagerMBean(SampledMBeanRegistrationProvider.java:118)
 [java]     at net.sf.ehcache.management.sampled.SampledMBeanRegistrationProvider.initialize(SampledMBeanRegistrationProvider.java:95)
 [java]     ... 46 more
```

Answer (score 17):

I had a similar problem. Surprisingly for me a `fork="yes"` in the java task worked like a charm. I didn't have to change any security policies.

I would try this:

```
<java fork="yes" classname ="${project.MainClass.name}">
    <classpath refid="run.classpath"/>
</java>
```

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem when trying to register an **MBean** with **ant**, and the solution was to add to `%JAVA_HOME%\jre\lib\security\java.policy` the following line:

> permission javax.management.MBeanTrustPermission "register";

reference: [message from ant-users](http://ant.1045680.n5.nabble.com/java-security-AccessControlException-when-using-Ant-but-runs-ok-when-invoking-java-from-console-td5713529.html)

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, Ant installs a `SecurityManager` when running your program and the way your JAAS security is configured, the code doesn't have the necessary privileges to run correctly.

By default no `SecurityManager` is installed, therefore your code runs normally when executed directly from the command line.

You can consult the [documentation for the Java Task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html) and look under "permissions".

Comment: that looks like a plausible explanation. I'll investigate it and come back.

Comment: Added permissions (see updated Ant java task) but still fails with the same stack trace.

Comment: Actually, I copied that use for the java.security.AllPermission class from here: http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/permissions.html. The use for the MBeanTrustPermission I copied from here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/management/MBeanTrustPermission.html#MBeanTrustPermission(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)