# ERROR Could not register mbeans java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("javax.management.MBeanTrustPermission" "register")

Tags: java, elasticsearch

When starting for example Elasticsearch 5.5 :

`main ERROR Could not register mbeans java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("javax.management.MBeanTrustPermission" "register")`

Answer (score 13):

Workaround with Oracle Java 1.8.0_131 is to open file `<jre>/lib/security/java.policy` and add this line to `grant` section (i.e. between curly brackets):

`permission javax.management.MBeanTrustPermission "register";`

Why workaround? The upright solution would be to specify extra `grant` section which code exactly should get this permission.

Answer (score 2):

got the same error and the answer is here [java.security.AccessControlException when using Ant, but runs ok when invoking java from console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12195868/java-security-accesscontrolexception-when-using-ant-but-runs-ok-when-invoking-j)

Append the grant section in java.policy file with
`permission javax.management.MBeanTrustPermission "register";`

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue when moving from a single instance to two instances locally.

I tried what Alice suggested above.  Even re-installed Elasticsearch (5.5.0).
I also updated my Java to the latest one for Linux provided by Oracle.

Nothing was working.  Then I discovered, that I couldn't just take the elasticsearch-5.5.0/config directory and rename it to elasticsearch-5.5.0/node1.

So... I had to leave that config directory in place and clone it to node1/node2.

EVEN if I configure path.config in the runtime args, ES still needs that base line config directory.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue on Ubuntu-16.04 system.
Solution:
ElasticSeearch service is not allowed to run for "ROOT" user. That's why change the ownership of elasticsearch folder with below command:
go to Elasticseach installation directory

**$ sudo chown -R user_name:user_Group elasticsearch-5.5.0**

$/bin/elasticsearch

this will start elasticsearch service. It is working form me perfectly.